# SqlAlchemy: State Management , how to persist an unserialize instance in session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

simple code like:

```
import pickle, cPickle
from app import session, redis 

class MyObj(DeclarativeBase):
    @classmethod
    def get(cls,id):
       key = cls.__name__+":"+str(id)
       cached = redis.get(key)
       if cached:
          # unserialize to cls instance
          return cPickle.loads(cached)
       record = session.query(cls).filter(cls.id==id).one()
       if record:
          # serialize and store to redis
          redis.set(key, pickle.dumps(record))
       return record


# first time , a normal orm instance returned from session query (uncached)
obj = MyObj.get(1)

# but the next requests, get cached from redis.
# and i want to delete the record
delobj = MyObj.get(1)
session.delete(delobj)
session.commit()
```

it raise an error like "instance xxx is not persisted"

i tried session.add(delobj) before delete, the Pending state is True ( state = inspect(delobj) ), but it still doesn't work for deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [merge](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#merging) cached instances to current session:

> `merge()` transfers state from an outside object into a new or already existing instance within a session.

From examples:

> An application is storing objects in an in-memory cache, shared by many `Session` objects simultaneously. `merge()` is used each time an object is retrieved from the cache to create a local copy of it in each Session which requests it. The cached object remains detached; only its state is moved into copies of itself that are local to individual Session objects.
>
> In the caching use case, it’s common to use the `load=False` flag to remove the overhead of reconciling the object’s state with the database. There’s also a “bulk” version of `merge()` called `merge_result()` that was designed to work with cache-extended Query objects - see the section [Dogpile Caching](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#examples-caching).

So:

```
   if cached:
      # unserialize to cls instance
      return session.merge(cPickle.loads(cached), load=False)
```

Remember to cache persisted objects of `cls` only, or you'll get the error:

```
InvalidRequestError: merge() with load=False option does not support objects transient (i.e. unpersisted) objects.  flush() all changes on mapped instances before merging with load=False.
```

A simple way to produce the aforementioned error:

```
obj = MyObj()
cached = pickle.dumps(obj)
obj2 = session.merge(pickle.loads(cached), load=False)
 ...
InvalidRequestError: merge() with load=False option does not support objects transient (i.e. unpersisted) objects.  flush() all changes on mapped instances before merging with load=False.
```

If on the other hand you first properly persist the object:

```
In [63]: obj = MyObj()

In [64]: session.add(obj)

In [65]: session.flush()

In [66]: obj.__dict__
Out[66]: 
{'id': 2,
 '_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState at 0x7fe6f380cac8>}

In [67]: cached = pickle.dumps(obj)

In [68]: session.commit()

In [69]: obj2 = session.merge(pickle.loads(cached), load=False)

In [70]: obj2 in session
Out[70]: True
```

Comment: awesome! it works.   but if i used load=False.  it raise Error:merge() with load=False option does not support objects transient (i.e. unpersisted) objects.  flush() all changes on mapped instances before merging with load=False.

Comment: It would seem you've somehow managed to cache objects that have not been persisted to the DB in your cache. The error is raised in [session.py](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L1761) when it cannot find a primary key for your cached instance... I think. From [State management](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html): "Transient - an instance that’s not in a session, and is not saved to the database; i.e. it has no database identity."

Comment: there were two http request in my app.   insert action and delete action.  i have listen the insert event @event.listens_for(cls, 'after_insert') , auto cached after inserted a record. and the second http request, get instance from cache(if cached) to delete it... and load=False doesn't work. maybe the reason is that they work in two different http request.

Comment: That's the root of your problem. The `target`s in *after_insert* event handler are not yet persisted. You can verify this yourself with adding something along the lines of `print("persisted?", inspect(target).persistent)` to your event handler. It'll print `persistent? False`.

Comment: From http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_events.html#after-flush: "The SessionEvents.after_flush() hook is called after the SQL has been emitted for a flush process, but **before the state of the objects that were flushed has been altered**" (emphasis added).

Comment: Actually it might be even more complicated than that, as the documentation has this to say about *after_insert*: "however these events need to be approached more cautiously, as they proceed within the context of the flush process that is already ongoing; many operations are not safe to proceed here."

Comment: You are right! I had bind after_update & after_insert for updating the cache. unexpectedly, when insert a record to bd, it called both after_update() & after_insert(), the target's state persistent is True in after_update and False in after_insert().    Otherwise, i had bind after_delete for deleting the cache. It's so ineffective, it always call after_update when update, insert or delete a record. So i want to deal the cache only in the after_update event, but how do i know it's going to update, insert or delete a record? is it possibly to use the state by inspect(target)?